# How to automatically start and keep socket.io instance in server

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, chat, socket.io-1.0

I have been developing a chat application using socket.io on Ubuntu and it needs to be run manually using the command line prior to test it on browser.

I am a PHP developer and how am I supposed to run the application on the server side without putting hands on the terminal?

Furthermore after executing the .js file via command line, I can test the application typing the host and a port typed on in the address bar. How can I overcome that if I am to embed the chat on a PHP page? Currently it looks like an external application.

The socket.io chat uses a .html page to draw the interface. How can I embed it in a PHP file?

Please help.

Comment: To keep socket.io process on server side - any daemon service like `forever`, `pm2` etc. Just render `socket.io-client` library on any page and do a connection with your socket server by specifying relevant `address:port`.

Comment: https://github.com/vgoodvin/ci-chat